# Construct boto sqs fifo MessageGroupId

Tags: python, boto, amazon-sqs

Currently using `boto` (not `boto3`) and trying to construct a message for a `FIFO` queue - but it keeps complaining about not having `MessageGroupId`. The (`boto`) documentation is completely silent on this field and I cannot figure out where to set this information.

setup:

```
from boto import sqs
from boto.sqs.message import Message
sqs = boto.resource('sqs')
conn = sqs.connect_to_region('my_region')
fifo = conn.get_queue('my-queue.fifo')
```

attempt 1:

```
>> m = Message()
>> m.attribute['MessageGroupId'] = 'group1'
>> m.set_body('test 1')
>> fifo.write(m)

SQSError:400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/">
    <Error>
      <Type>
        Sender
      </Type>
      <Code>
        MissingParameter
      </Code>
      <Message>
        The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId.
      </Message>
    <Detail/>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>
    {blah}
  </RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Ok, fine, it doesn't belong as a `message.attribute`, what about ... `message.message_attributes`

```
>> m = Message()
>> m.message_attributes['MessageGroupId'] = 'group1'
>> m.set_body('test 1')
>> fifo.write(m)

## same error as above
```

Maybe I need to pass it in as an argument?

```
>> M = Message(MessageGroupId='group1')

TypeError: unexpected keyword arg
```

So, my question is: how do I construct a valid `FIFO` `message` in `boto`? Let's start with `MessageGroupId`, but if there's something different about `MessageDeduplicationId`, please include that info as well (I'm not using `ContentBasedDeduplication`).

Comment: I doubt that it's possible, as boto maintenance seems to be restricted to critical fixes and FIFO is a queue type with significant implementation differences that was introduced relatively late in the game.  Perhaps someone can provide a more authoritative answer than this.

Comment: Oh, is `boto` just not being maintained/updated in favor of `boto3`? I thought they were both still going; but that would make more sense as to why certain (newer) features aren't available

Comment: That's my impression.